# Save splited text lines opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I need to split text on image into lines and then save every line as new img.

I understand how to split in lines, but how i can save all lines as img?

there is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


img = cv2.imread("1.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
th, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
hist = cv2.reduce(threshed,1, cv2.REDUCE_AVG).reshape(-1)

th = 2
H,W = img.shape[:2]
uppers = [y for y in range(H-1) if hist[y]<=th and hist[y+1]>th]
lowers = [y for y in range(H-1) if hist[y]>th and hist[y+1]<=th]

for y in uppers:
    cv2.line(img, (0,y), (W, y), (255,0,0), 1)

for y in lowers:
    cv2.line(img, (0,y), (W, y), (0,255,0), 1)
    

cv2.imshow("imgTestingNumbers", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: img1]

Comment: So, are you saying that `uppers` and `lowers` contain the row locations of the interline gaps?  If you have that, then you just need to extract each band.  You do that with `img1 = img[0:uppers[0],:]`, and then you can `cv2.imwrite` that.  Do that in loop, just like you do with the lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("/path/to/your_img.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
th, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
hist = cv2.reduce(threshed,1, cv2.REDUCE_AVG).reshape(-1)

th = 2
H,W = img.shape[:2]
uppers = [y for y in range(H-1) if hist[y]<=th and hist[y+1]>th]
lowers = [y for y in range(H-1) if hist[y]>th and hist[y+1]<=th]

img_num = 1
for i in range(len(uppers)):
    cv2.imwrite('so_splited_imgs_' + str(img_num) + '.jpg', img[uppers[i]:lowers[i],:])
    img_num += 1
```

Output images will be written in the same directory as the code. You might want to provide the full/relative path in case you want it written in a separate directory.

Comment: This work, except it throws a `IndexError: list index out of range` error on `lowers[i]` because `lowers[i]` and `uppers[i]` are not the same length. `uppers[i]` is longer by 1. I'm not sure if that is due to how `uppers` and `lowers` are generated. But it does save images per line. Nice one :) Been looking for something like this to create OCR training input files.